SearchKit Requires Timestamp when Searching by Date
I thought that there was a bug in SearchKit when I was searching for contributions by date and getting no results, but I realise now that it requires a precise timestamp, which is bizarre.
Effectively, you can't use "=" for the date, but have to use between the adjacent midnights.
Is there a setting that allows you to search by date without timestamp?
